Проблема с зависанием скрипта, определяющего наличие аутентификации на rtsp-потоке
Я пишу свой скрипт на Python, который находит открытые камеры с помощью shodan.
От API у меня есть около 10 url-адресов, работающих через rtsp (предположительно) и не требующих аутентификации.
Но, как правило, API shodan`a не всегда выдаёт свежую информацию, и url-адресам нужна дополнительная проверка на наличие аутентификации.
Сам отрывок из кода:
def some_func(ip):
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(f"rtsp://{ip}/").isOpened() # В ip включен порт
    if not cap:
        print("CLOSED:", ip)
    else:
        print("OPENED:", ip)

Если поток открыт (то есть не требует аутентификации) возвращается True, иначе False.

Суть проблемы в том, что я пытался сделать это через библиотеку opencv на python через метод VideoCapture — если поток открыт, то где-то через короткий промежуток времени код выполняется, но если rtsp-поток закрыт (то есть выводятся ошибки типа 404, 403 и т. п.), то скрипт встаёт намертво (через 2 минуты может отвиснуть).
Вот пример вывода:
[rtsp @ 000002cccd9d3f80] method DESCRIBE failed: 404 Stream Not Found

Я бы смирился с этим, если бы у этого метода был бы параметр timeout, но я его не нашёл!
Может есть какой-нибудь параметр, отвечающий за timeout в VideoCapture, или любая другая библиотека, имеющая похожий метод с таймаутом?

А если не использовать метод isOpened(), а пытаться прочитать кадр ret, frame = cap.read()? ret - это флаг успешности получения кадра. Сделать счетчик неудачных попыток, если превысит лимит, то вернуть False, как только ret == True, то вернуть из функции True.

Оно работает также, я выяснил что проблема в самом методе VideoCapture(), т.к. там нельзя выставить timeout, ну а мне критически важна возможность его изменения

В результате поиска я узнал, что метод VideoCapture заимствует весь поток, в итоге я нашел решение проблемы через библиотеку threading с помощью ChatGPT, т.к. в потоке как раз можно выставить timeout, что мне и требовалось.
Вот отрывок кода решающий мою проблему:
def check_rtsp_stream(ip, Timeout):
result = {'open': False}  # словарь для хранения результата

def worker():
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(f"rtsp://{ip}/")
    result['open'] = cap.isOpened()
    cap.release()

thread = threading.Thread(target=worker)
thread.start()
thread.join(timeout=Timeout)  # ждем завершения потока с таймаутом

# Проверяем, завершился ли поток
if thread.is_alive():
    print("TIMEOUT:", ip)
    return False  # если поток не завершился, считаем, что поток закрыт

return result['open']  # возвращаем результат проверки


# Пример использования
if check_rtsp_stream(ip):
    print("OPENED:", ip)
else:
    print("CLOSED:", ip)

